# How to store an image in persistent store

Tags: blackberry, persistent, persistent-storage

I am working on a BlackBerry application that has an "Image Button". The "Image Button" can change from "ON to OFF" and vice versa between each clicks. Now what I am trying to do is, when the app is closed and loaded again, this "Image Button" should load as its last state. If the "Image Button" was set to "ON" and the app closed, on next load it will load as "ON". When creating the Image Button, if the value is set to "true", the image loads as "ON" even though it was created as off-on. I create the ImageButton outside the constructor:

```java
LabeledSwitch onImg=new LabeledSwitch(off,on,off,on,true);
```

Then inside the constructor, I tried to check the last image state and so create the Image Button again accordingly. However, (boolean)((Boolean) persistentHashtable.get("image")).booleanValue() throws a CastException even though it compiles alright.

```java
persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);

 if (persistentObject.getContents() == null) 
 {
    persistentHashtable = new Hashtable();
    persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
 } else {
    persistentHashtable = (Hashtable) persistentObject.getContents();
     }

  if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("image")) 
 {
     boolean booleanVal = (boolean)((Boolean) persistentHashtable.get("image")).booleanValue();
     if (booleanVal==true)
     {
         onImg=new LabeledSwitch(on,off,on,off,true);
     }
     else
     {
         onImg=new LabeledSwitch(off,on,off,on,false);
     }
 }
```

I am saving the state of the image on exit:

```java
public boolean onClose() 
    {
        int choose=Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Are you sure Want to Exit?");
        if(choose==Dialog.YES)
        {
            if(onImg._on)
             persistentHashtable.put("image", Boolean.TRUE);

            else
                persistentHashtable.put("image", Boolean.FALSE); 
            System.exit(0);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Please guide. For reference, below is the LabeledSwitch class used to create the image button:

```java
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;

public class LabeledSwitch extends Field {
    private String _textOn;
    private String _textOff;

    private int _textWidth;
    private int _textHeight;

    private int _totalWidth;
    private int _totalHeight;

    private Bitmap _imageOn;
    private Bitmap _imageOnFocus;
    private Bitmap _imageOff;
    private Bitmap _imageOffFocus;

    public boolean _on; //chngd
    private boolean _selected;

    private Font _labelFont;

    private static MenuItem _changeOptionsItem = new ChangeOptionMenuItem();

    private int _textColour = 0x888888;
    private int _textColourFocus = 0x000000;

    private int _horizontalTextImageGap;

    private Bitmap _switchImage;  
    private String _labelText;  
    int mHeight;
    int mWidth;

    public LabeledSwitch(){}

    public LabeledSwitch( Bitmap imageOn
                , Bitmap imageOff
                , Bitmap imageOnFocus
                , Bitmap imageOffFocus
                , boolean onByDefault ) {
        super( Field.FIELD_VCENTER );

        //_textOn = textOn ="";
        //_textOff = textOff ="";

        _imageOn = imageOn;
        _imageOff = imageOff;
        _imageOnFocus = imageOnFocus;
        _imageOffFocus = imageOffFocus;
        _on = onByDefault; 
        _selected = false;

        _horizontalTextImageGap = _imageOn.getHeight() / 3;

    }

    public void applyFont() {
        _labelFont = getFont().derive( Font.PLAIN, _imageOn.getHeight()  );
    }

    /**
     * Change the state of the switch
     * @param on - if true, the switch will be set to on state
     */
    public void setOn(boolean on) {
        _on = on;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean getOnState() {
        return _on;
    }

    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return _totalWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return _totalHeight;
    }

    protected void layout( int width, int height ) {
        // 
        _textWidth = Math.max( _labelFont.getAdvance( _textOn + "a" ), _labelFont.getAdvance( _textOff + "a" ) )-36;
        _textHeight = _labelFont.getHeight();

        _totalWidth = _imageOn.getWidth() + _horizontalTextImageGap + _textWidth;
        _totalHeight = _imageOn.getHeight();

        mWidth = getPreferredWidth();
        mHeight = getPreferredHeight();
        setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);

       // setExtent( _totalWidth, _totalHeight );
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g ){
        Font oldFont = g.getFont();
        int oldColor = g.getColor();

        try { 

            if( _on ) {
                _switchImage = g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS) ? _imageOnFocus : _imageOn;
            } else {
                _switchImage = g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS) ? _imageOffFocus : _imageOff;
            }

            g.setFont( _labelFont );

            // Determine Label Colour
            g.setColor( g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS) ? _textColourFocus : _textColour );

            // Label
            g.drawText( _on ? _textOn : _textOff, 0, ( getHeight() - _textHeight ) / 2, DrawStyle.RIGHT, _textWidth ); 

            // Image
            //g.drawBitmap( _textWidth + _horizontalTextImageGap, 0, _switchImage.getWidth(), _switchImage.getHeight(), _switchImage, 0, 0 );
            g.drawBitmap(0, 5, mWidth, mHeight, _switchImage, 0, 0);
        } finally {
            g.setFont( oldFont );
            g.setColor( oldColor );
        }
    }

    public void paintBackground( Graphics g ) {}

    protected void drawFocus( Graphics g, boolean on ){
        // Paint() handles it all
        g.setDrawingStyle( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS, true );
        paint( g );
    }

    protected boolean keyChar( char key, int status, int time ){
        if( key == Characters.SPACE || key == Characters.ENTER ) {
            toggle();            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
        toggle();            
        return true;    
    }

    protected boolean invokeAction(int action){
        switch( action ) {
            case ACTION_INVOKE: {
                toggle(); 
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.invokeAction( action );
    }

    protected boolean trackwheelClick( int status, int time ){        
        if( isEditable() ) {
            toggle();            
            return true;
        }
        return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);
    }

    /**
     * Toggles the state of the switch
     */
    private void toggle(){
        _on = !_on;
        invalidate();
        fieldChangeNotify( 0 );
    }

    public void setDirty( boolean dirty ){
        // We never want to be dirty or muddy
    }

    public void setMuddy( boolean muddy ){
        // We never want to be dirty or muddy
    }    

    protected void makeContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu){
        super.makeContextMenu(contextMenu);
        if((Ui.getMode() < Ui.MODE_ADVANCED) && isEditable()) {
            contextMenu.addItem(_changeOptionsItem);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @category Internal InnerClass
     */
    static class ChangeOptionMenuItem extends MenuItem {
        ChangeOptionMenuItem() {
            super("Toggle", 30270, 10);
        }

        ChangeOptionMenuItem(String text) {
            super(text, 30270, 10);
        }

        public void run() {
            LabeledSwitch theSwitch = (LabeledSwitch)getTarget();
            theSwitch.toggle();
        }

        public int getPriority() {
            return 100 + (getTarget().isMuddy() ? 1000 : 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please specify what is your current output?

Comment: The normal thing would be to save the state, and then on startup initialize the button according to the saved state. You are instead trying to persist a GUI component.

Comment: To expand on Mister Smith's excellent comment, for saving the state that corresponds to a 2-state UI button/switch, normally you would just save a `Boolean` value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).  That's the cleanest implementation.  That said, it should certainly be *possible* to save the state as an image filename, so your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: I tried to create the button inside the constructor by verifying whether the persistent store is null or has the last state saved. However, this resulted in a "NullPointerException". @Nate I do not really know how to save as a boolean value. Can you explain this a bit? And with regards to the file name, is there some issue with the way I have called the persistent store?

Comment: @Ajmal my current output is an Image Button as the one created outside the constructor. It does not load as the last saved state.

Comment: Use `persistentHashtable.put("image", Boolean.TRUE)` to save the state as a simple `Boolean`.  When you read the state back in, if the saved value is `Boolean.TRUE`, then use "on.png" as your image.  Regarding the code you've posted, is the first large block all one chunk of code, or have you pasted code from multiple methods there?  It doesn't make sense to me that you would call `persistentHashtable.put("image", ...)`, and then immediately test `persistentHashtable.containsKey("image")`.  That test can never fail the way you've written it.

Comment: @Nate, I am lost. Like I mentioned, the Image Button is created outside the constructor. The LabeledSwitch class that I am using has a boolean value as part of the constructor. When that value is set to "true", the Image Button is always loaded as "ON". I have edited my code to reflect where is this being called. Moreover, I am unable to check whether persistentHashtable.containsKey("image") is true or false; throws a Cast Exception. I have edited my question to include these codes. Kindly advice.

Comment: Ok, your edits look good.  That was what I was suggesting, in terms of changing the code to save a `Boolean` instead of a `String`.  However, if you look at my first comment, I say that this was **not** the reason your code isn't working correctly.  It's just a suggestion (from Mister Smith) to clean things up.  I would take a look at Eugen's answer below, which could be a reason why the value isn't being saved. Also, I'm a little unclear on this code: `new LabeledSwitch(off,on,off,on,true)`.  You seem to call that constructor with different off/on values, depending on the saved boolean.

Comment: ... that doesn't look right.  Depending on the persistent boolean value, shouldn't you just call LabeledSwitch `setOn()` with a different value?  Shouldn't the constructor arguments be the same, either way?  Or am I misunderstanding your `LabeledSwitch` class?

Comment: Yes,the difference in constructors is to create the appropriate image (ON or OFF) depending on the boolean value (last state). As for @Eugen's answer below, I have earlier worked with saving string values to persistent store and it has worked fine without using commit(). So I believe that should not really be an issue. Issue is if(onImg._on) is always true since the Image Button created outside the constructor is always created as ON (if the last value of LabeledSwitch is true).

Comment: But, calling the `setOn()` method will tell the `LabeledSwitch` whether to display the **on** or the **off** image.  Shouldn't a switch in the **on** state still have the same values for `_imageOn` and `_imageOff` as a switch in the **off** state?  It should just be a matter of which image is displayed, which is determined by the flag that gets set when you call `setOn()`.  Right?  Also, I've always called `commit()` when I've used the Persistent Object APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I think there may be multiple problems here. I do think Eugen is right about the `commit()` call.

However, I think the `LabeledSwitch` class is being used incorrectly.  I'm going to guess that you didn't write that class?  I only say that because I see multiple coding conventions within that one class.

Having seen multiple custom BlackBerry UI classes like this, I believe that this is the way that class is supposed to work:

1. The class can toggle between two visual states, which you can define by passing the class a PNG image that represents the **on** state, and the **off** state.
2. The class can be toggled between those states by calling the `setOn()` method, with either a `true` or `false` value for the parameter.  The value of that parameter will determine which PNG file is drawn in the class's custom `paint()` method
3. The class's original author intends for you to use the `setOn()` and `getOnState()` methods to modify and access the current state of the switch.  You should change this

```java
public boolean _on;
```

to this:

```java
private boolean _on;
```

If you want to know if the switch is on, ask `onImg.getOnState()`.

By the way, I would recommend a different name for your switch than `onImg`.  That's a very confusing name.  It should be something like `onOffSwitch`, or `toggleSwitch`, or `fooSwitch`, if the switch is used to switch off and on something called *foo*.  Naming it `onImg` is confusing, in the context of the member variable `_imageOn`, which should **always** represent the image that gets displayed when the switch is **on**.

So, to summarize, instead of this:

```java
 if (booleanVal==true)
 {
     onImg=new LabeledSwitch(on,off,on,off,true);
 }
 else
 {
     onImg=new LabeledSwitch(off,on,off,on,false);
 }
```

use something like this:

```java
 onOffSwitch = new LabeledSwitch(on, off, on, off, true);
 onOffSwitch.setOn(booleanValue);
```

or

```java
 onOffSwitch = new LabeledSwitch(on, off, on, off, booleanValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see the following required code to have your persistent object stored:

```
persistentObject.commit();
```

I hope this is just several extras from your code, otherwise you always rewrite value before reading it, which is probably not expected. So the 'read' code should not stay after 'write', because it doesn't have any sense.